# cfhttp call taking over to the login screen in callback

Tags: coldfusion

I am doing a simple cfhttp call, using cf10.

The url i am fetching is straight, i just paste that url in the address bar and it shows me the results.

The same link i try in cfhttp call, Note the below links are dummy

http://www.fakeurl.net/login2.asp?id=myid&password=mypasswd&t=page.asp&pe=000

now my cfhttp call:

```
<cfset urlAddress="#trim(link)#"> 
    <cfhttp url="#urladdress#" method="GET" resolveurl="No" throwOnError="Yes"/>
    <cfoutput>#CFHTTP.FileContent#</cfoutput>
```

I took advice of Adrian and here is my next try:

```
<cfset address = "http://www.fakeurl.net/login2.asp">
<cfhttp url="#address#" method="POST" throwOnError="Yes" result="objGet" useragent="#CGI.http_user_agent#">
        <cfhttpparam type="Header" name="Accept-Encoding" value="deflate;q=0">
        <cfhttpparam type="Header" name="TE" value="deflate;q=0">
        <cfhttpparam type="url" name="id" value="myid">
        <cfhttpparam type="url" name="password" value="mypasswd">
        <cfhttpparam type="url" name="t" value="page.asp">
        <cfhttpparam type="url" name="rp" value="000">
    </cfhttp> 
    <cfoutput>#objGet.FileContent#</cfoutput>
```

now it gives me

> 302

error

Comment: I'm not finding a question in your statements, and not really able to follow those either.

Comment: Ditto to what Chris said. Obviously something is going wrong with your cfhttp call, but it is impossible to tell what that something is from your description. 1) What is the actual result of the code above? If you are getting an error message, please post it. 2) What did you expect to happen instead?

Comment: *now it gives me 302 error* [HTTP 302](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302) means redirection. You need to re-read [the cfhttp docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7ffc.html). Hint: There is an attribute for that ;-)

Comment: it means it is logging in and needs a redirect url, but i set to redirect="no", it shows me url with username is passed to the query string and when i click the link, it says username/password required and is moved back to the login screen again

Comment: Then the issue may be what [Adrian mentioned](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27258012/104223) about sessions. Have a look at this entry on maintaining sessions with cfhttp: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/725-maintaining-sessions-across-multiple-coldfusion-cfhttp-requests.htm

Answer (score 0):

The very basic of what you need:

```
<cfhttp 
     url="http://www.fakeurl.net/login2.asp?id=myid&password=mypasswd&t=page.asp&pe=000" 
     method="get" 
     resolveurl="yes">

<cfdump var='#cfhttp#' abort>
```

Which resolves.

I think you will find things you are looking inside the `<cfdump>` I added. Then be able to pick out certain things you need...

You can then parse it into a variable and trim it and do other things from there.

Comment: The OP mentioned that is just a "fake" url ;-) So the problem is something else, but .. it is hard to say what that is without more details.

Answer (score 0):

re: "Taking over to the login screen" - The link works in your browser because you've logged into the site and have an active session. Via CFHTTP, the is no valid session. It's a request unrelated to your browser session, so the URL redirects to the login screen. You would have to pass an ID/PWD as part of the request (not via query string parameters) or gain a session token that can be part of your request to get that content.

Comment: Hi Adrian, I think we can try that, but as how do i pass those values, should i use cfhttpparam, if yes, how, because i need to pass the `username,password,t,pe`. another thing is: When i call that `fakeurl` through browser, its redirects to the second page where actual results are shown, so i hope with what we call `cfhttp`, it will work same way